# Vertical space between two inline blocks stack

Tags: html, css

I have 6 div's in my code that I want to be next to each other. I don't know why div "five" and "six" don't work. I used the same rules at the other forth and it works. When I remove "font-size:0" from "container1" it's teh result that I want but there are some spaces between div's. Any ideas?

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.container1{
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 8%;
  margin-right: 8%;
  font-size: 0;
}
.three{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color:aquamarine;
}
.four {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: dodgerblue
}
.five {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: red;
}
.six {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  background-color: black;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40%;   
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>jadalnia</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
  <div class="four"></div>
  <div class="five"></div>
  <div class="six"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: What's "piec" and "szesc"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS instead of yours.

```css
  body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.container1{
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 8%;
  margin-right: 8%;
}
.three{
  float:right;
  width: 60%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color:aquamarine;
}
.four {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: dodgerblue
}
.five {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: red;
}
.six {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  background-color: black;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40%;   
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>jadalnia</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
  <div class="four"></div>
  <div class="five"></div>
  <div class="six"></div>
</div>
```